# Android - mapping ostream output properly to android native log?

Tags: android, c++, logging, io

I want to use iostreams for logging via both `__android_log_print` and `fstream`. 
My question is, is there any good way to turn for example:

```
cout << "Hello," << " my name is : " << "Kaiser and my ID is: " << 3 << endl;
```

into something which can be sent to the android logging function, `__android_log_print`? How do I format it properly?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The way to write to some arbitrary destination from within the program is to derive a class from `std::streambuf` and override its `overflow()` and `sync()` functions. You could then create an `std::ostream` with a pointer to an object of this class. To write to multiple destinations at once you'd use a `teebuf` which a stream buffer writin to two (or more) stream buffers. Googling for "teebuf" should yield several examples.

Answer (score 0):

I would try restarting adb with `log.redirect-stdio` set to `true`:

```
$ adb shell stop
$ adb shell setprop log.redirect-stdio true
$ adb shell start
```

But this will work only on emulators or development devices, it won't work on a production device though (at least, without root).